# How to scroll page instead of item in Vaadin ComboBox?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Vaadin8 ComboBox can be scrolled with mousewheel but it scrolls one item at a time. In Vaadin7 it was scrolling the pages. I found this old ticket from V7 but seems untouched: [Combobox Mousewheel-Scrolling does not scroll pages. #7788](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/7788)

I have hundreds of items so it gets quite laborious to go through the list.

Is it possible to scroll the page with mousewheel and not an item? Any suggestions how?

Comment: Valid question, but why "torture" users with hundreds of items to scroll over? Is there no way to use the fiter capabilities of the combobox to narrow the options down?

Comment: @cfrick There is, ComboBox supports "searching" and 90% cases that is the way to select an item. But sometimes the scrolling has its place in finding the desired item - in those cases scrolling the pages would be more efficient.

Comment: So you want to change how comboboxes have been behaving since the beginning of (their) time? I do not understand when the "other 10%" would ever come into effect (please share, when is filtering not good enough?),  and why it is then not acceptable to then have a standard scrolling behaviour.

Comment: It was scrolling pages up to 7.6.7.  Then it was changed to per item.

Comment: I think what people are trying to say is, no this isn't doable without changing the underlying Vaadin source code

Comment: Can you clarify please if this is an expected behaviour or is a vaadin framework bug or exist a way to configure combo box component?.This bug continues to happen with vaadin 7.7.14.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small hack that can be useful to someone. If you set the `combobox.setPageLength(your_item.size())` and the list of `your_item` is large enough to not fit in the window, the scroll bar will appear

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvLo7.png)

Comment: Nice alternative for the issue - though not exactly answer to the original question. Also noticed that if you put `combobox.setPageLength(0)` will have the same effect and it will be dynamic based on browser size. Of course for scroll bar to appear you will need to have "enough" of items to not fit on screen all at once.